# Determining price for discreet periods from a list of trades

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a discreet list of historic trades from a commodity exchange, with a datetime and a value e.g.

```
tradeTime                  |  price
-----------------------------------
2014-06-11T00:21:12+02:00  |  647.24
2014-06-11T00:23:12+02:00  |  700.18
2014-06-11T00:28:12+02:00  |  750.23
2014-06-11T00:40:00+02:00  |  767.81
2014-06-11T00:51:12+02:00  |  711.46
```

Now I want to be able to create a list of the price every hour. So the three logical possibilities are:

1. There was 1 trade in that period - great, that's the price (opening and closing)
2. There were multiple trades - the first is the opening price and the last is the closing
3. There were no trades - the opening & closing price should be the most recent trade prior to the period.

So with the above example, looking at 10min increments, the output should be something like:

```
period         |  open    | close
--------------------------------
00:20 -> 00:30 |  648.24  | 750.23
00:30 -> 00:40 |  750.23  | 767.81
00:40 -> 00:50 |  767.81  | 711.46
```

-

```
SELECT * FROM sales BETWEEN From_date AND To_date
```

possibly with a `MIN()`, `MAX()` for the dates to select the price? I am not sure how this would all come together with the

Comment: without a sample our hands would be tight! as Idon't know even why you're using `From_date > @RangeTill OR To_date < @RangeFrom` I don't see the logic here, since you only need to list the prices between two periods with more conditions, so using `BETWEEN From_date AND To_date` would do that without the need of parameters. all logical possibilities could be done without parameters, unless if you wan't to specify it manually. (or over a loop maybe).

Comment: @iSR5 I was planning to do this with a loop, so I could do a query like "hourly price over 2 year period" or "daily price over 3 year period"

Comment: there is no reason then to use a loop. if you need more help, you should provide a sample good enough to cover all three possibilities. so we ensure that you'll have the right query.

Comment: Hence, `MIN`, `MAX`, `OVER(Partition By ..) ` all these functions will be your friends for this query.

Comment: @iSR5 Okay, does that edit help?

Comment: is there any identity columns? as using these two columns alone is not a wise a decision

Comment: @iSR5 I could add a transactionId to each row

Comment: What is this date format? Can it be assumed to be simply `00:21:12`, `00:23:12`, etc.?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn it’s ISO 8601 formatted reliably

Comment: Do provided answers solve your issue? If not recheck your expected output please. Because there are inconsistencies in your task conditions and expected output. And can a price be associated with two periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
WITH qq AS (
  SELECT cast('2014-06-11T00:00:00' as datetime) as startTime,
         dateadd( minute, 10, cast('2014-06-11T00:00:00' as datetime)) as endTime
  UNION ALL
  SELECT endTime, dateadd( minute, 10, endTime )
  FROM qq
  WHERE endTime < cast('2014-06-12T00:00:00' as datetime) 
)
SELECT startTime, endTime,
       coalesce( opening, opening1 ) as opening,
       coalesce( closing, opening, opening1 ) as closing
FROM (
   SELECT qq.startTime, qq.endTime,
       (SELECT TOP 1 price FROM table1 t1 
        WHERE t1.tradeTime >= qq.startTime AND t1.tradeTime < qq.endTime
        ORDER BY t1.tradeTime ) As opening,
       (SELECT TOP 1 price FROM table1 t1 
        WHERE t1.tradeTime >= qq.startTime AND t1.tradeTime < qq.endTime
        ORDER BY t1.tradeTime DESC ) As closing,
       (SELECT TOP 1 price FROM table1 t1 
        WHERE t1.tradeTime < qq.startTime
        ORDER BY t1.tradeTime DESC ) as opening1
   FROM qq
) x
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b9363/6

```
|            startTime |              endTime | opening | closing |
|----------------------|----------------------|---------|---------|
| 2014-06-11T00:00:00Z | 2014-06-11T00:10:00Z |  (null) |  (null) |
| 2014-06-11T00:10:00Z | 2014-06-11T00:20:00Z |  (null) |  (null) |
| 2014-06-11T00:20:00Z | 2014-06-11T00:30:00Z |  647.24 |  750.23 |
| 2014-06-11T00:30:00Z | 2014-06-11T00:40:00Z |  750.23 |  750.23 |
| 2014-06-11T00:40:00Z | 2014-06-11T00:50:00Z |  767.81 |  767.81 |
| 2014-06-11T00:50:00Z | 2014-06-11T01:00:00Z |  711.46 |  711.46 |
| 2014-06-11T01:00:00Z | 2014-06-11T01:10:00Z |  711.46 |  711.46 |
| 2014-06-11T01:10:00Z | 2014-06-11T01:20:00Z |  711.46 |  711.46 |
| 2014-06-11T01:20:00Z | 2014-06-11T01:30:00Z |  711.46 |  711.46 |
| 2014-06-11T01:30:00Z | 2014-06-11T01:40:00Z |  711.46 |  711.46 |
| 2014-06-11T01:40:00Z | 2014-06-11T01:50:00Z |  711.46 |  711.46 |
| 2014-06-11T01:50:00Z | 2014-06-11T02:00:00Z |  711.46 |  711.46 |
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with a list of hours.  Because you may not have trades, you need to generate this.  Assuming you only want a handful of hours -- say all hours in one day -- a recursive CTE is sufficient:

```
with hours as (
      select cast('2014-06-11' as datetime) as yyyymmddhh
      union all
      select dateadd(hour, 1, yyyymmddhh)
      from hours
      where dateadd(hour, 1, yyyymmddhh) < '2014-06-12'
     )
```

Then, you can do what you want using `apply`:

```
with hours as (
      select cast('2014-06-11' as datetime) as yyyymmddhh
      union all
      select dateadd(hour, 1, yyyymmddhh)
      from cte
      where dateadd(hour, 1, yyyymmddhh) < '2014-06-12'
     )
select h.*, opening.price, closing.price
from hours h outer apply
     (select top 1 t.*
      from t
      where tradetime < dateadd(hour, 1, yyyymmddhh)
      order by (case when cast(tradetime as date) = cast(yyyymmddhh as date) and
                          datepart(hour, tradetime) = datepart(hour, yyyymddhh)
                     then 1
                     else 0
                end),
               (case when cast(tradetime as date) = cast(yyyymmddhh as date) and
                          datepart(hour, tradetime) = datepart(hour, yyyymddhh)
                     then tradetime
                end) asc,
               tradetime desc
    ) opening outer apply
    (select top 1 t.*
      from t
      where tradetime < dateadd(hour, 1, yyyymmddhh)
      order by (case when cast(tradetime as date) = cast(yyyymmddhh as date) and
                          datepart(hour, tradetime) = datepart(hour, yyyymddhh)
                     then 1
                     else 0
                end),
               tradetime desc
    ) closing;
```

Comment: What is `cte`? I am getting error `Invalid object name 'cte'`

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,

I'm not sure if my solution actually helps you, since i'm not in a situation where I can check if the code works or why it doesn't, I would try something along these lines:

```
SELECT prices FROM trades WHERE(SELECT MIN(DATEPART(MINUTE, trades.dates)), 
MAX(DATEPART(MINUTE, trades.dates)) WHERE(SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(HOUR, 
trades.dates));
```

The idea is to sub-query the minimum and maximum values for the minutes in each distinct hour, and then query the related prices for minute 1 and minute 60, so that you obtain both the opening and closing prices.

I hope this helps you to move forward on your problem, or at least gives you a hint on a possible solution.

Best wishes,

M.S.

Answer (score 0):

Following query should give you a start.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Disp,
       (
        CASE WHEN [Open] IS NOT NULL THEN [Open]
        ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 PRICE FROM @Table 
            WHERE Datepart(MINUTE, TradeTime) / 10 < O.Diff )
        END
       ) AS [Open]
       ,(
        CASE WHEN O.[Open] IS NOT NULL THEN [Open]
        ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 PRICE FROM @Table 
            WHERE Datepart(MINUTE, TradeTime) / 10 < O.Diff )
        END
       ) AS [Close]

       FROM
       (
        SELECT  
        D.Disp
       ,D.Diff
       ,FIRST_VALUE(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY GRP  
                           ORDER BY TradeTime ASC) AS [Open]
       ,FIRST_VALUE(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY GRP 
                           ORDER BY TradeTime DESC)  AS [Close],
        TradeTime
   FROM (VALUES (0,'00:01->00:10'),
                (1,'00:10->00:20'), 
                (2,'00:20->00:30'), 
                (3,'00:30->00:40'), 
                (4,'00:40->00:50'), 
                (5,'00:50->00:59') 
                ) D(Diff,Disp) 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Datepart(MINUTE, TradeTime) / 10 AS GRP, 
                         TradeTime, 
                         Price 
                  FROM   @Table 
                  GROUP  BY Datepart(MINUTE, TradeTime) / 10, 
                            TradeTime, 
                            Price) T 
                  ON T.GRP = D.Diff 
              ) O
```

**Complete Example :**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(TradeTime DATETIME, Price DECIMAL(15,2))
INSERT INTO @Table
  SELECT * FROM
  (VALUES 
  (CAST('2018-02-18 13:04:46.920' AS DATETIME)  ,  647.24)
 ,(CAST('2018-02-18 13:05:46.920' AS DATETIME) ,  700.18)
 ,(CAST('2018-02-18 13:15:46.920' AS DATETIME)  ,  750.23)
 ,(CAST('2018-02-18 13:24:46.920' AS DATETIME) ,  767.81)
 ,(CAST('2018-02-18 14:26:46.920' AS DATETIME)  ,  711.46)


   ) TAB(TradeTime, Price)



      SELECT DISTINCT Disp,
       (
        CASE WHEN [Open] IS NOT NULL THEN [Open]
        ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 PRICE FROM @Table 
            WHERE Datepart(MINUTE, TradeTime) / 10 < O.Diff )
        END
       ) AS [Open]
       ,(
        CASE WHEN O.[Open] IS NOT NULL THEN [Open]
        ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 PRICE FROM @Table 
            WHERE Datepart(MINUTE, TradeTime) / 10 < O.Diff )
        END
       ) AS [Close]

       FROM
       (
        SELECT  
        D.Disp
       ,D.Diff
       ,FIRST_VALUE(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY GRP  
                           ORDER BY TradeTime ASC) AS [Open]
       ,FIRST_VALUE(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY GRP 
                           ORDER BY TradeTime DESC)  AS [Close],
        TradeTime
   FROM (VALUES (0,'00:00->00:10'),
                (1,'00:10->00:20'), 
                (2,'00:20->00:30'), 
                (3,'00:30->00:40'), 
                (4,'00:40->00:50'), 
                (5,'00:50->00:59') 
                ) D(Diff,Disp) 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Datepart(MINUTE, TradeTime) / 10 AS GRP, 
                         TradeTime, 
                         Price 
                  FROM   @Table 
                  GROUP  BY Datepart(MINUTE, TradeTime) / 10, 
                            TradeTime, 
                            Price) T 
                  ON T.GRP = D.Diff 
              ) O
```

**Sample Output**

```
Disp            Open        Close
--------------------------------------
00:00->00:10    647.24      647.24
00:10->00:20    750.23      750.23
00:20->00:30    767.81      767.81
00:30->00:40    647.24      47.24
00:40->00:50    647.24      647.24
00:50->00:59    647.24      647.24
```